# apache common csv format into string

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have this code. It show proclist on screen, How I can write all prcoese into public string?

```
try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") 
+"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe /FO CSV");
      try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new I 
nputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
          CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(input).getRecords().stream().map(r   -
 >r.get(0)).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Don't print it. String join it

Comment: Please be careful to your indentation, your lines are splitted on multiple line, even a Class name is wrapped. It is not the best to understand a snippet quickly.